# How to algorithmically add notes to an existing midi file relative to positions of existing notes in python

Tags: design, algorithms, python

I have a midi file that I'd like to algorithmically add notes to relative to other notes that already exist in the midi file using python, or if it's easier using a different language I'm open to that as well.

So basically, I have a midi file with a bunch of notes, and let's say I'd like to add 5 or 6 new notes surrounding each of the existing notes with timing differences that are randomly generated (for example time differences with a random amount of milliseconds difference between -10 and 10).

So with each note already existing in the midi file I'd add 5 or 6 new ones surrounding it to a new midi file, offset by a randomly determined amount of milliseconds. Also, if possible, I'd like to randomly vary the velocities of each new note in the same manner relative to the note in the original midi file.

The only part I'm not sure how to do is read and write into a midi file based on its note onset contents?

Comment: Please don't cross post. Your question is on topic here.

Comment: Reading file formats is always tricky.  You either have to find the spec and implement it, reverse engineer it, or (my preference) find a library that already does it for you.  Manipulating a data structure is much easier than trying to modify a file format via binary.  So...  is there a midi python library?  This has a whole MIDI section: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

Comment: Sorry Chris, I wasn't sure where the question would fit better.

Thanks for the link Kieveli, I'll try playing around with some of those libraries and see if I can make some progress. Thanks for getting me headed in the right direction.

Comment: @Kieveli: It's only cringe-worthy in the sense that it's very difficult to read a MIDI specification.  Not much has changed in the last 20 years, even with the addition of MIDI over USB.  But the interface is still sound and reliable.

Comment: http://www.pjb.com.au/midi/free/MIDI.py works perfectly for what I'm trying to do. It can parse bytes literals from a MIDI file (`x=open('file.mid','rb')` then `y=x.read()` to get a format that the functions will take, with y being the variable taken as a MIDI input) into a structured format, listing out each note so that it can be easily edited and modified, and then once the list is edited as desired it can be taken back in to return bytes literals (called `changed_y` for example) that can be written as a new MIDI file (`z=open('newfile.mid','wb')` then `z.write(changed_y)`). It's perfect.

Comment: I once implemented a tool that would load multisamples into a synth via sysex commands against the synth's rhythm bank.  Basically the synth had no concept of multisamples, but it could trigger different samples depending on key velocity in the rhythm bank.  Like Kieveli said, trying to do pretty much anything with MIDI at the byte level is an exercise in frustration -- so easy to make one tiny mistake and have absolutely nothing as a result (hard to debug things with no symptom).  You really REALLY _REALLY_ need a library -- preferably one that's been around the block a few times.